# utf8_general_ci - is it standard Unicode?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have a database, with a table set to `utf8_general_ci`

It contains the following cyrillic data: `Дabc123`

*The MySQL `ORD` function returns the code of the first character*... so ....

```
SELECT ORD('myColumn') FROM myTable
```

... should return `DECIMAL 1044` but instead returns `DECIMAL 53396`

Why? 53396 is a Chinese character...

Comment: 53396 is five latin characters.

Comment: It's a decimal number, I said in the question.

Comment: I think you missed my funny joke.

Answer (score 4):

[`ORD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ord) does not return the [*code point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of the first character; it returns a Mysql-specific "code" that is calculated in the manner the documentation mentions.

Comment: hmm but HEX(LEFT(myColumn)) returns the same incorrect value... strange